# How to combine OrderBy and OrderByDescending Expression into one single Expression?

Tags: c#

How can I combine several expressions into one single expression and pass it as parameter?

```
// how to combine order by expression???
Expression<Func<Student, dynamic>> orderby = o => o.Marks desc then o.Name; /* ??? */
```

Now I can combine expressions but how to indicate desc & asc?
I can use extension method like OrderBy().ThenBy().ThenByDescending()
How can I take the expression out?

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // this is the normal extension method way
      IEnumerable<Student> students = Student.All.Where(o => o.Marks > 50).OrderByDescending(o => o.Marks).ThenBy(o => o.Name).Skip(10).Take(10);

      // construct filter, and I can combine this kind of expression
      Expression<Func<Student, bool>> filter = o => o.Marks > 50;

      // but how to combine order by expression???
      Expression<Func<Student, dynamic>> orderby = o => o.Marks desc then o.Name; /* ??? */

      IEnumerable<Student> howtogetstudents = GetStudents(filter, orderby, 2, 10);
    }

    static IEnumerable<Student> GetStudents(Expression<Func<Student, bool>> filter,
      Expression<Func<Student, dynamic>> orderby, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
      IQueryable<Student> students = Student.All;

      return students.Where(filter).OrderBy(orderby).Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }
  }

  class Student
  {
    Student() { }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public decimal Marks { get; set; }

    public static IQueryable<Student> All { get { return null; } }
  }
```

Comment: I think you will need to do it the long way and build the expression tree yourself, this is going to get complicated. What are you tying to accomplish by doing this all in one expression?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I joined a team which is developing a MVC website, the structure is there Controlloer->Service->Repository,I was told inside the repo no business logic allowed,so I need to pass the logic in a more generic way. I feel something is not very correct.

Comment: Why does the ordering need to be done in the repository?  Why not order it after it is returned to the service layer?

Comment: @recursive I don't need the whole list, I only need certain page. And repo layer does not return IQueryable, but concrete list, this is by original design.

Comment: Ouch.  Sorry to hear of your quandary.  It sounds like you've been buried by implausible architecture.  Good luck.